# Spark CSV Read Ignore characters

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I'm using Spark 2.2.1 through Zeppelin.

Right now my spark read code is as follows:

`val data = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",").option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls","true").csv("listings.csv")`

I've noticed when I use the `.show()` function, the cells are shifted to the right. On the CSV all the cells are in the correct places, but after going through Spark, the cells would be shifted to the right. I was able to identify the culprit: The quotations are misplacing cells. There are some cells in the CSV file that written like so:

{TV,Internet,Wifi,"Air conditioning",Kitchen,"Indoor fireplace",Heating,"Family/kid friendly",Washer,Dryer}

Actual output (please note that I used `.select()` and picked some columns to show the issue I am having.):

```
|         description|           amenities|      square_feet|               price|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|This large, famil...|"{TV,Internet,Wif...|          Kitchen|""Indoor fireplace""|
|Guest room in a l...|   "{TV,""Cable TV""|         Internet|                Wifi|
```

Expected output:

```
|         description|           amenities|      square_feet|               price|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|This large, famil...|"{TV,Internet,Wif...|       1400      |   $400.00          ||
|Guest room in a l...|   "{TV,""Cable TV""|       1100      |   $250.00          ||
```

Is there a way to get rid of the quotations or replace them with apostrophes? Apostrophes appear to not affect the data.

Comment: can you explain more of what you mean with "misplacing cells"? Maybe show the actual and expected output? I ran your code and data with copy & paste in my Zeppelin notebook (version 0.8.1) and do not see anything unexpected.

Comment: @mike Hi Mike, I revised the original question. I stated incorrectly and meant to say that the cells are shifted to the right after the CSV is passed through Spark read. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

What your are looking for is the `regexp_replace` function with the syntax `regexp_replace(str, pattern, replacement)`.

Unfortunately, I could not reproduce your issue as I didn't know how to write the listings.csv file.

However, the example below should give you an idea on how to replace certain regex patterns when dealing with a data frame in Spark.

#### This is reflecting your original data

```scala
data.show()

+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+
|description| amenities|square_feet|   price|
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+
|'This large| famil...'|       '{TV|Internet|
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+
```

#### With regexp_replace you can replace suspicious string patterns like this

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_replace
data.withColumn("amenitiesNew", regexp_replace(data("amenities"), "famil", "replaced")).show()

+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+-------------+
|description| amenities|square_feet|   price| amenitiesNew|
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+-------------+
|'This large| famil...'|       '{TV|Internet| replaced...'|
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+-------------+
```

Using this function should solve your problem with the problematic characters by replacing them. Feel free to use regular expression in that function.